# How come a MainActor isolated mutable stored property gives a sendable error?

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

I'm trying to conform a class to `Sendable`. I have some mutable stored properties which are causing issues. However, what I can't understand is that a MainActor isolated property doesn't allow my class to conform to Sendable. However, if I mark the whole class a `@MainActor`, then it's fine. However, I don't actually want to conform the whole class to `@MainActor`.

As an example, take this code:

```
final class Article: Sendable {
  @MainActor var text: String = "test"
}
```

It gives this warning: `Stored property 'text' of 'Sendable'-conforming class 'Article' is mutable`.

Can someone explain why? I thought that being isolated to an actor would make it fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is warning you that your class has a mutable property. That mutable property can be accessed from outside of Swift concurrency and is therefore not safe.

Consider the following:

```swift
final class Foo: Sendable {
    @MainActor var counter = 0   // Stored property 'counter' of 'Sendable'-conforming class 'Foo' is mutable
}
```

We can now consider the following property and method of a view controller, which interacts with `counter` directly:

```swift
let foo = Foo()

func incrementFooManyTimes() {
    DispatchQueue.global().async { [self] in
        DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 10_000_000) { _ in
            foo.counter += 1
        }
        print(foo.counter)   // 6146264 !!!
    }
}
```

NB: If you do have set the “Swift Concurrency Checking” build setting to “Minimal” or “Targeted”, the above will compile with only the aforementioned warning. (If you change this to “Complete”, it becomes a hard error.)

In short, you have marked the as `@MainActor`, but there is nothing to stop other threads from interacting with this property of the class directly. For a type to be `Sendable`, it must either:

- be immutable;
- manually synchronize its properties; or
- be an `actor`

---

If you are going to have a non-actor be `Sendable` with mutable properties, you have to implement the thread-safety yourself. E.g.:

```swift
final class Foo: @unchecked Sendable {
    private var _counter = 0
    private let queue: DispatchQueue = .main    // I would use `DispatchQueue(label: "Foo.sync")`, but just illustrating the idea

    var counter: Int { queue.sync { _counter } }

    func increment() {
        queue.sync { _counter += 1 }
    }
}
```

And

```swift
func incrementFooManyTimes() {
    DispatchQueue.global().async { [self] in
        DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 10_000_000) { _ in
            foo.increment()
        }
        print(foo.counter)   // 10000000
    }
}
```

Obviously, you could also restrict yourself to immutable properties and no synchronization would be necessary. But I assume you needed mutability.

Now, in this mutable scenario, you can use whatever synchronization mechanism you want, but hopefully this illustrates the idea. In short, if you are going to allow it to mutate outside of Swift concurrency, you have to implement the synchronization yourself. And because we are implementing our own synchronization, we tell the compiler that it is `@unchecked`, meaning that you are not going to have the compiler check it for correctness, but rather that burden falls on your shoulders.

---

Obviously, life is much easier if you use an actor and stay within the world of Swift concurrency. E.g.:

```swift
actor Bar {
    var counter = 0

    func increment() {
        counter += 1
    }
}
```

And:

```swift
let bar = Bar()

func incrementBarManyTimes() {
    Task.detached {
        await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
            for _ in 0 ..< 10_000_000 {
                group.addTask { await self.bar.increment() }
            }
            await print(self.bar.counter)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first code snippet with `concurrentPerform` doesn't compile for me. What is `self`? Is this function supposed to be in a class? How can you access `counter` when it is isolated to `@MainActor`?

Comment: The `self` is a view controller and `incrementFooManyTimes` is just a random method. Re “How can you access `counter`” question, that’s my whole point. If you have `@MainActor` property inside a random class, nonisolated code (such as my random method in a view controller) can still access and interact with it. Sure, if you access it from Swift concurrency, the compiler will enforce the rich actor isolation rules, but if not, the `@MainActor` doesn't provide any functional benefit. But if it is an actor (like my `Bar` example), then the compiler enforces all the necessary checks.

Comment: Okay, now it compiles for me after putting it in a `UIViewController`. I totally did not expect this though. If it were in a class without a superclass, or one marked with `@MainActor`, it wouldn't have worked. I wonder what's special about UIKit types... In any case, yeah I do agree with your point in general.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the Swift Evolution proposals, it seems like complex `Sendable` conformance checking just hasn't been designed/implemented yet.

From the [global actors proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0316-global-actors.md#using-global-actors-on-a-type), it is said that types which are marked with a global actor implicitly conform to `Sendable`.

> A non-protocol type that is annotated with a global actor implicitly conforms to `Sendable`. Instances of such types are safe to share across concurrency domains because access to their state is guarded by the global actor.

So you don't even need `: Sendable` if you mark your final class with `@MainActor`!

On the other hand, the [proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0302-concurrent-value-and-concurrent-closures.md#sendable-conformance-checking-for-classes) for `Sendable` mentions:

> **Sendable conformance checking for classes**
>
> [...] a class may conform to Sendable and be checked for memory safety by the compiler in a specific limited case: when the class is a final class containing only immutable stored properties of types that conform to Sendable:
>
> ```
> final class MyClass : Sendable {
>     let state: String
> }
> ```

Basically, every stored property in your class need to be a `let` if you don't mark your final class with a global actor.

I have no been able to find anything else in these two documents, or other proposals on  Swift Evolution that are relevant.

So the current design doesn't even care about whether you add `@MainActor` to a property. The two sufficient conditions for a final class to conform to `Sendable`

The `Sendable` proposal also mentions:

> There are several ways to generalize this in the future, but there are non-obvious cases to nail down. As such, this proposal intentionally keeps safety checking for classes limited to ensure we make progress on other aspects of the concurrency design.